# Identifying what weights to give to each class in a Random Forest

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I am using a randomForest package in R to discriminate between 4 categories (*i.e. I want to predict to what class an observation belongs*). My data consists of 80k+ observations and is heavily unbalanced with around 70% of all observations being in a single category.
I want to decrease the class error for the other 3 categories (*optionally, without completely trashing the error rate of the 1st class*) and so I am experimenting with assigning different weights to the classes.

I was wondering if there's a good method to determine in advance what would be an optimal class weights or does it all depend on what class error am I willing to tolerate?

Many thanks!

Comment: I would look at the variable importances.  You could then scale by the importance.  Do you know that the other columns are as informative as the first?  You can select rows that are "full rank" and then only a subset of reduced rank so that the total samples is twice the full rank count.  You can do a variation on cross validation where you repeat your analysis on different samplings of the "reduced rank" rows.  I would let that tell me what the variable importance is.  I would then use the full-set importance and the reduced sample importance to generate the weights.  Do you have sample data?

Comment: Thanks for the input @EngrStudent . I am not sure if I understand your answer, though. My question is about weighting the classes that you are trying to predict ( classwt argument in RandomForest library in R), not weighting the variables.